# adding another letter to already existing autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My title doesn't make any sense, but here's an example of what I want to do:

If I type `abc` it should be replaced with `ABC`.  Additionally, if I type `abcc` it should replace with `Always Be Closing`.  In other words `abc` auto-capitalizes, and `abcc` spells this acronym out.

Currently, I have...

`:*:abc::ABC`

`:*:abcc::Always Be Closing`

...so when I type `abcc` it just comes out as `ABCc`

I know there's a lot more to it than this, but I can't figure out (new to this).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` are your hotstring options, where the `*` indicated that it will replace it as soon as you type the last letter `c` in `abc`. Removing the `*` like this will make it replace only if you press a non-alphanumeric character: (or enter, or whatever)

```
::abc::ABC
::abcc::Always Be Closing
```

The above lines is probably what you want. (You can add the `c` option to make it case sensitive for example, if you want)

Also see the [documentation](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Hotstrings.htm) of Hotstrings, in particular the **Options** block.

Comment: nevermind, got it figured out...

:*:abc::
Send, ABC
Input, Var, V L1
if (Var = "c")
 Send {BS 4}Always Be Closing
return

Comment: Oh, you figured it out. I was looking at [`#InputLevel`](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm), which seems to might be able to do what you want in a cleaner way, though I'm not entirely sure how.

Comment: @user2679060 If you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. However, waiting for input in a hotstring that's supposed to fire immediately defeats its own purpose. On the basis of the code in your question, dropping the asterisk from the `abc` hotstring (`::abc::ABC` and `:*:abcc::Always Be Closing`) would be functionally equal to your solution, but more standard AHK, better readable and would contain less unnecessary code.